# Android web app webview is displaying web pages same for both tablet and smartphone

Tags: browser, webview

I have created a web app that has a native webview element to display the web pages. On my galaxy nexus things are displayed at a size I expect and everything looks good.

On my xoom tablet after installing the app, all text and images are displayed in the same proportion to the device as on my smartphone, causing the app to look terrible, text and images show pixels. This is similar to how honeycomb had the ability to enlarge smartphone sized apps to the bigger tablet screens. Everything worked correctly but it just looked bad because your essentially zooming in on something that is already at full scale.

Both the devices have the same resolution (1280 x 800), which is kind of why it makes sense that they would display the web pages the same.

What is the method to make the larger screen display the web page so images and text are zoomed out and not pixelated (if that's even a word)?

Answer (score 0):

when you are setting the size use dp instead of px and I would also look at your hdpi,ldpi,mdpi folders and the media in there